# python : how to remove part of contour map by mouse event(matplotlib)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

when the mouse click on the map I want to remove(zero'd) what is below this click

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line = ax.plot([0],[-3])  # empty line

xlist = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 100)
ylist = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlist, ylist)
Z = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
cp = ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)
fig.colorbar(cp) # Add a colorbar to a plot
ax.set_title('Filled Contours Plot')
ax.set_ylabel('y (cm)')
def onclick(event):
    print('%  x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          ( event.button,
           event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)


plt.show()
```

plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
def onclick(event):
    print('%  x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          (event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))
    Z[np.where(ylist>=event.ydata)[0][0],
      np.where(xlist>=event.xdata)[0][0]] = 0.
    ax.contourf(X, Y, Z)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
```

The new line finds the closest index on the grid where mouse `event` is detected (because of the interpolation) by using `np.where` and setting `Z` value to zero. Then, `contourf` is called again and drawn.